# How to Query multiple database residing on SQL HAG 2012 & SQL HAG 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016

Need help!

I am designing a solution where we need to maintain multiple instances of different databases residing on SQL HAG 2012 and SQL HAG 2016. Other than Linked Servers, are there any ways to query both the database in real-time? I am looking for native options if available. Data mirroring can help but are there any other options?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not Linked Servers? This is why they exist

Comment: Isn't the best practice to avoid using linked servers, especially in a HAG? Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to linked servers for querying data in different instances is executing [SQL OpenRowSet](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-sql-select-from-stored-procedure-using-openquery-openrowset.aspx) command with connection properties defined within the command as in following example

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=KODYAZ\SQL2017;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
  'select firstname from AdventureWorks.Person.Person') AS p
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI',
    'Server=KODYAZ\SQL2017;Trusted_Connection=yes;user_id=sa;password=kodyazpwd',
    'select top 3 firstname from AdventureWorks.Person.Person'
) AS p
```

Of course before you need to [enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-Ad-Hoc-Distributed-Queries.aspx) on your SQL Server instance

Comment: Thanks for sharing the OpenRowSet option. Not the best but certainly an option.